# Watching a vuex state does not give me access to it's value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my `store.js`, I have:

```js
state: {
  User: false
},
```

I am not using `getters` and `User` will be an object once it's set. In my component, I have:

```js
export default {
  name: "ConversationsList",
  mixins: [conversationMixin],
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["User"])
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      conversations: false,
      datedConversations: false
    };
  },
  watch: {
    User: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal);
```

But `newVal` is not an object with simple properties. They appear to be functions:
How can I access them as regular properties?

[image: User object getters and setters]

Comment: Maxbe only as a useful note: you have to use `deep: true` if you want to set a `watcher` to an object. Also the arguments `oldVal` and `newVal` are not available if you are watching an object or an array. See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access them just like ordinary properties:

Access it in `script`:

```js
const email = User.email
```

Access it in `template`:

```html
<template>
  <span>{{ User.email }}</span>
</template>
```

Vue applies getter and setter to each property, to implement it's reactivity. As you see from the code above, each property is initialised with it's getter and setter, so every time you change it, Vue can rerender the appropriate parts of your template.

I would recommend you read about [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).